# Como obtener el elemento con mas ocurrencias dentro de un array?

Tags: javascript, array

> La intención es obtener el elementos mas frecuente, no el numero de repeticiones, sino el elemento con mas apariciones dentro del array.

He intentado obtener un único valor,( el elemento con mas apariciones dentro del array) pero no se me ocurre como. Solo he podido obtener los elementos no repetidos y su numero de repeticiones ambos como un array nuevo.

Ejemplo: [2,4,5,4,7,8,4,2,4,2,8] // debería devolver 4

Agradezco la ayuda. Estoy aprendiendo JS.

```js
let array = [2,4,5,4,7,8,4,2,4,2,8]

let orden = array.sort((a,b)=>a-b)


let contador = 1;
let unicos =[]
let repeticiones = []


  for(i=0;i<orden.length;i++){
  if(orden[i+1]===orden[i]){
      contador ++
  }else{
    unicos.push(orden[i])
    repeticiones.push(contador)
    contador = 1; 
  }
   
  }
 console.log(unicos)
 console.log(repeticiones)
```

Comment: Ya casi lo tienes. Solo te faltaría recorrer el arreglo `repeticiones` para hallar el índice del mayor. Luego `unicos[indice_mayor]` es el número con más repeticiones

Comment: Si quieres lo hago y lo pongo como respuesta pero te recomiendo intentarlo primero.

Comment: @Fedex7501 No veo como!

Comment: Alguien ya respondió por mí. Hasta optimizó el código y todo.

Answer (score 3):

lo que puedes hacer es crear un objeto donde vas a guardar todas las repeticiones por cada elemento en tu caso algo así:
El 2 se repite 3 veces , el 4 se repite 4 veces y asi sucesivamente.

```
{2:3, 4:4, 5:1, 7:1, 8:2}
```

Entonces lo que podrias hacer es:

```js
let array =  [2,4,5,4,7,8,4,2,4,2,8];

/* Crear un objeto que tenga las repeticiones de cada elemento */
let conteo = {};
/*creamos una variable inicializada en 0 para guardar la repeticion maxima*/
let rep_max=0;
/*creamos una variable que contendrá el elemento con repeticion maxima*/
let elem_max;

/*recorres el array con forEach para cada elemento y realizas un conteo por elemento repetido */
array.forEach((elem) => {
    if(conteo[elem]){
        conteo[elem] += 1;
    } else {
        conteo[elem] = 1;
    }
    //Aqui comparas los conteos, se almacenará el mayor y tambien obtendrás el elemento
    if(rep_max<conteo[elem]){
        rep_max=conteo[elem];       
      elem_max=elem;
    }
    
});
console.log("Objeto con repeticiones");
console.log(conteo);
console.log("repeticion maxima: "+rep_max);
console.log("elemento: "+elem_max);
```